# How to prevent Sql Error : Must declare the scalar variable "@result"?

Tags: sql-server

I tried on one query without paging concept like below

```
alter procedure temp
@result varchar(50)
as
begin
if @result='all'
begin
    select Receive_Payment.PayId,Receive_Payment.UserId,C_Register.Name,C_Register.UserName
      ,Packages.PackageName,Packages.PackagePeriod,Receive_Payment.InstallCharge
      ,Receive_Payment.AmountToPay,Receive_Payment.PyingAmount,Receive_Payment.Balance
      ,Receive_Payment.DiscountToPay,Area.AreaName,C_Register.MobNo
      ,C_Register.CreatedDate,Employee.EmpName,Receive_Payment.PayBy
      ,Receive_Payment.BankName,Receive_Payment.ChequeNo,Receive_Payment.ChequeDate

     FROM Receive_Payment INNER JOIN C_Register ON Receive_Payment.UserId = C_Register.UserId 
                      INNER JOIN Packages ON Receive_Payment.PackageId = Packages.PackageId
                      INNER JOIN Area ON C_Register.AreaId = Area.AreaId 
                      INNER JOIN Employee ON Receive_Payment.EmpId = Employee.EmpId
     where C_Register.AccountExpiry=Receive_Payment.OldExpiryDate 
end
if @result='single'
begin
    select Receive_Payment.PayId,Receive_Payment.UserId,C_Register.Name,C_Register.UserName
      ,Packages.PackageName,Packages.PackagePeriod,Receive_Payment.InstallCharge
      ,Receive_Payment.AmountToPay,Receive_Payment.PyingAmount,Receive_Payment.Balance
      ,Receive_Payment.DiscountToPay,Area.AreaName,C_Register.MobNo
      ,C_Register.CreatedDate,Employee.EmpName,Receive_Payment.PayBy
      ,Receive_Payment.BankName,Receive_Payment.ChequeNo,Receive_Payment.ChequeDate

     FROM Receive_Payment INNER JOIN C_Register ON Receive_Payment.UserId = C_Register.UserId 
                      INNER JOIN Packages ON Receive_Payment.PackageId = Packages.PackageId
                      INNER JOIN Area ON C_Register.AreaId = Area.AreaId 
                      INNER JOIN Employee ON Receive_Payment.EmpId = Employee.EmpId
     where C_Register.AccountExpiry=Receive_Payment.OldExpiryDate And Packages.PackageName='2000 package'
 end
 end
```

It's working good by execute it `temp '1'` or `temp 'all'`
But with paging concept I applied same this procedure in like below store-procedure.

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get_Payment]    
       @PageIndex INT = 1
      ,@PageSize INT = 10
      ,@RecordCount INT OUTPUT
      ,@discount float output
      ,@paidamount float output
      ,@tableName varchar(50)=NULL
      ,@ColumnName VARCHAR(50)=NULL 
      ,@Value VARCHAR(50)=NULL
      ,@result varchar(50)=NULL
AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      DECLARE @cmd AS NVARCHAR(max)

      CREATE TABLE #payInfo 
        ( 
        rownum         INT,            
           payId INT,
            userid         INT, 
           NAME           VARCHAR(100), 
           username       VARCHAR(100), 
           packageperiod  VARCHAR(50), 
           packagename    VARCHAR(100),
           installCharge  float,
            amountToPay   float,
             balance        float, 
           pyingamount    float, 
            discountToPay float,
            areaName varchar(100),
             mobno          VARCHAR(50), 
             createddate    DATE,
             empname        VARCHAR(100), 
             PayBy          VARCHAR(100),
            bankName        varchar(100),
            chequeNo        varchar(100),
            chequeDate      date
        )    

      SET @cmd ='if @result=''all''
      begin
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
      (
            ORDER BY Receive_Payment.PayId desc 
      )AS rownum          
      ,Receive_Payment.PayId,Receive_Payment.UserId,C_Register.Name,C_Register.UserName
      ,Packages.PackageName,Packages.PackagePeriod,Receive_Payment.InstallCharge
      ,Receive_Payment.AmountToPay,Receive_Payment.PyingAmount,Receive_Payment.Balance
      ,Receive_Payment.DiscountToPay,Area.AreaName,C_Register.MobNo
      ,C_Register.CreatedDate,Employee.EmpName,Receive_Payment.PayBy
      ,Receive_Payment.BankName,Receive_Payment.ChequeNo,Receive_Payment.ChequeDate

     FROM Receive_Payment INNER JOIN C_Register ON Receive_Payment.UserId = C_Register.UserId 
                      INNER JOIN Packages ON Receive_Payment.PackageId = Packages.PackageId
                      INNER JOIN Area ON C_Register.AreaId = Area.AreaId 
                      INNER JOIN Employee ON Receive_Payment.EmpId = Employee.EmpId
     where C_Register.AccountExpiry=Receive_Payment.OldExpiryDate
     end
     if @result=''single''
      begin
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
      (
            ORDER BY Receive_Payment.PayId desc 
      )AS rownum

      ,Receive_Payment.PayId,Receive_Payment.UserId,C_Register.Name,C_Register.UserName
      ,Packages.PackageName,Packages.PackagePeriod,Receive_Payment.InstallCharge
      ,Receive_Payment.AmountToPay,Receive_Payment.PyingAmount,Receive_Payment.Balance
      ,Receive_Payment.DiscountToPay,Area.AreaName,C_Register.MobNo
      ,C_Register.CreatedDate,Employee.EmpName,Receive_Payment.PayBy
      ,Receive_Payment.BankName,Receive_Payment.ChequeNo,Receive_Payment.ChequeDate


     FROM Receive_Payment INNER JOIN C_Register ON Receive_Payment.UserId = C_Register.UserId 
                      INNER JOIN Packages ON Receive_Payment.PackageId = Packages.PackageId
                      INNER JOIN Area ON C_Register.AreaId = Area.AreaId 
                      INNER JOIN Employee ON Receive_Payment.EmpId = Employee.EmpId
     where C_Register.AccountExpiry=Receive_Payment.OldExpiryDate And '+@tableName+'.'+@ColumnName+'='''+@Value+'''
     end'   

       Insert into #payInfo 
       EXEC(@cmd)
      SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*) FROM #payInfo
           select @discount = sum(discountToPay) FROM #payInfo
           select @paidamount = sum(pyingamount) FROM #payInfo
      SELECT * FROM #payInfo
      WHERE rownum BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1

      DROP TABLE #payInfo 
      print @cmd    
END
```

Then throwing an error by executing from code-behind side like below

> Must declare the scalar variable "@result".
>       Must declare the scalar variable "@result".

```
if @result='all'
      begin
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
      (
            ORDER BY Receive_Payment.PayId desc 
      )AS rownum

      ,Receive_Payment.PayId,Receive_Payment.UserId,C_Register.Name,C_Register.UserName
      ,Packages.PackageName,Packages.PackagePeriod,Receive_Payment.InstallCharge
      ,Receive_Payment.AmountToPay,Receive_Payment.PyingAmount,Receive_Payment.Balance
      ,Receive_Payment.DiscountToPay,Area.AreaName,C_Register.MobNo
      ,C_Register.CreatedDate,Employee.EmpName,Receive_Payment.PayBy
      ,Receive_Payment.BankName,Receive_Payment.ChequeNo,Receive_Payment.ChequeDate


     FROM Receive_Payment INNER JOIN C_Register ON Receive_Payment.UserId = C_Register.UserId 
                      INNER JOIN Packages ON Receive_Payment.PackageId = Packages.PackageId
                      INNER JOIN Area ON C_Register.AreaId = Area.AreaId 
                      INNER JOIN Employee ON Receive_Payment.EmpId = Employee.EmpId
     where C_Register.AccountExpiry=Receive_Payment.OldExpiryDate
     end
     if @result='single'
      begin
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
      (
            ORDER BY Receive_Payment.PayId desc 
      )AS rownum

      ,Receive_Payment.PayId,Receive_Payment.UserId,C_Register.Name,C_Register.UserName
      ,Packages.PackageName,Packages.PackagePeriod,Receive_Payment.InstallCharge
      ,Receive_Payment.AmountToPay,Receive_Payment.PyingAmount,Receive_Payment.Balance
      ,Receive_Payment.DiscountToPay,Area.AreaName,C_Register.MobNo
      ,C_Register.CreatedDate,Employee.EmpName,Receive_Payment.PayBy
      ,Receive_Payment.BankName,Receive_Payment.ChequeNo,Receive_Payment.ChequeDate


     FROM Receive_Payment INNER JOIN C_Register ON Receive_Payment.UserId = C_Register.UserId 
                      INNER JOIN Packages ON Receive_Payment.PackageId = Packages.PackageId
                      INNER JOIN Area ON C_Register.AreaId = Area.AreaId 
                      INNER JOIN Employee ON Receive_Payment.EmpId = Employee.EmpId
     where C_Register.AccountExpiry=Receive_Payment.OldExpiryDate And C_Register.UserId='147'
     end
```

So how to prevent from this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like below

```
if @result is null
      begin
      SET @cmd ='SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
      (
            ORDER BY Receive_Payment.PayId desc 
      )AS rownum

      ,Receive_Payment.PayId,Receive_Payment.UserId,C_Register.Name,C_Register.UserName
      ,Packages.PackageName,Packages.PackagePeriod,Receive_Payment.InstallCharge
      ,Receive_Payment.AmountToPay,Receive_Payment.PyingAmount,Receive_Payment.Balance
      ,Receive_Payment.DiscountToPay,Area.AreaName,C_Register.MobNo
      ,C_Register.CreatedDate,Employee.EmpName,Receive_Payment.PayBy
      ,Receive_Payment.BankName,Receive_Payment.ChequeNo,Receive_Payment.ChequeDate


     FROM Receive_Payment INNER JOIN C_Register ON Receive_Payment.UserId = C_Register.UserId 
                      INNER JOIN Packages ON Receive_Payment.PackageId = Packages.PackageId
                      INNER JOIN Area ON C_Register.AreaId = Area.AreaId 
                      INNER JOIN Employee ON Receive_Payment.EmpId = Employee.EmpId
     where C_Register.AccountExpiry=Receive_Payment.OldExpiryDate'
     end
     else if @result=2
      begin
       SET @cmd ='SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
      (
            ORDER BY Receive_Payment.PayId desc 
      )AS rownum

      ,Receive_Payment.PayId,Receive_Payment.UserId,C_Register.Name,C_Register.UserName
      ,Packages.PackageName,Packages.PackagePeriod,Receive_Payment.InstallCharge
      ,Receive_Payment.AmountToPay,Receive_Payment.PyingAmount,Receive_Payment.Balance
      ,Receive_Payment.DiscountToPay,Area.AreaName,C_Register.MobNo
      ,C_Register.CreatedDate,Employee.EmpName,Receive_Payment.PayBy
      ,Receive_Payment.BankName,Receive_Payment.ChequeNo,Receive_Payment.ChequeDate


     FROM Receive_Payment INNER JOIN C_Register ON Receive_Payment.UserId = C_Register.UserId 
                      INNER JOIN Packages ON Receive_Payment.PackageId = Packages.PackageId
                      INNER JOIN Area ON C_Register.AreaId = Area.AreaId 
                      INNER JOIN Employee ON Receive_Payment.EmpId = Employee.EmpId
     where C_Register.AccountExpiry=Receive_Payment.OldExpiryDate And '+@tableName+'.'+@ColumnName+'='''+@Value+''''   
         end
```

put conditions out from the comments

Comment: aah got it..veru very thanq sir.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `EXEC(@Cmd)`, `@Cmd` statement will run in another session. Your local variables like `@result` will not valid in that session it's valid just in your session.

So You can do one of this solutions:

1. Edit your `@Cmd` statement to a statement with changing `@result` from `@Cmd` to `' + @result + '`, by this change you will have the value of it instead of variable name.
2. Edit your transaction and take out all needs of `@result` from `@Cmd` to your transaction, I mean that check values of `@result` in your transaction not in `@Cmd`.